# How to avoid too much recursive error when it seems there is no way to avoid

Tags: javascript, runtime-error

I have to reduce my wall of text which means that I cannot explain what the code is about. Yet the problem is:
this code generate fractions which meet some requirements and specifications.
this requirements lead to a huge number of calls of the function CommonFactor, like 3000000 or more. I'm using this javascript code inside of max msp, and I can generate the fraction but I cant avoid the Error message about to many recursive calls.
So what Can I do about it?!

```js
var unit = 0;
var maxSubdivision = 0;
var minSubdivision = 0;
var fractionN = 0;
var fractionD = 0;


function CommonFactor(numerator, denominator) {
 return denominator == 0 ? numerator: CommonFactor(denominator, numerator % denominator);

}

function length( minutes, bpm) {
 unit = 60*minutes*Math.round(bpm/60);
 minSubdivision = 2
 maxSubdivision = unit*10;
}


function genrandSub(){
 var random = Math.floor(Math.random() *(maxSubdivision-(minSubdivision-1))+(minSubdivision));
 var unitD = unit;
 var factor = CommonFactor(random, unitD);
 if(factor != 1 && random != unit) {
  random = random/factor;
  unitD = unitD/factor;
  if(random <= 16 && unitD <= 32) {
   fractionN = random;
   fractionD = unitD;
  }
  else{
   genrandSub();
  }
 }
 else{
  genrandSub();
 }
}

function findConvergence(nA,dA, nB, dB){
 var whenB = nB * dA;
 var whenA = dB * nA;
 var length = dA * whenA;
 factor = CommonFactor(nA, length);
 nA = nA/factor;
 length = length/factor;
 if(nA == 1 && length == unit){
  return true;
 }
 else{
  return false;
 }
}

function genPattern (hwMany) {
 var subdivisionN = new Array();
 var lengthD = new Array();
 for(var i = 0; i < hwMany; i ++){
  if(i == 0) {
   genrandSub();
   subdivisionN[i] = fractionN;
   lengthD[i] = fractionD;
  }
  else {
   var index = 0;
   rand = genrandSub();
   if(findConvergence (fractionN, fractionD,subdivisionN[i-1], lengthD[i-1]) != true){
    var state = false;
    while(state == false){
     rand = genrandSub();
     state = findConvergence (fractionN, fractionD,subdivisionN[i-1], lengthD[i-1]);
     index += 1;
     if(index == 6){
      state = true;
     }
    }
    if(index == 6){
     genPattern(hwMany);
    }
    else{
     subdivisionN[i] = fractionN;
     lengthD[i] = fractionD; 
    }
   }
   else{
    subdivisionN[i] = fractionN;
    lengthD[i] = fractionD;
   }
  }
 }
  for( var k = 0 k < subdivisionN.length; k++){
    console.log(subdivisionN[k]);
    console.log(lengthD[k]);
  }
}
length(60,60);
genPattern(4);
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to format the first half of your question into legible paragraphs and reduce your code down to a [mcve]. The wall of text and code is a lot to digest to comprehend what exactly is going on.

Comment: What have you tried to debug this?  For example, for CommonFactor you could add an alert showing the values at every level, or add a nesting / recursion level variable and break once the level reaches (say) 25 to see what values cause it to repeat forever.  To find "bad" values you could write a test function that generates 2 random values and then calls CommonFactor -- have it run until it trips the alert.

Comment: Hello Dave I did what you suggest .So I create a global variable index to see how many call I have in the function CommonFactor using index++.  it printed 32683  sometimes even more. The function Common Factor is used by the other functions and one of the functions - genPattern - is a recursive one, because I realised that, sometimes and depending of the fraction that were generated by the random function, this genPattern function needs to  run again because it reach a blind alley so to speak. That's Why I have a while loop there.

Answer (score 0):

Hello everyone I solved the problem but I can not explain the reason. The way I solved the problem seems to me to be logical, but I would like someone to comment and explain me better. I want to learn more.
So my previous code I had:

```js
function genPattern (hwMany) {
 var subdivisionN = new Array();
 var lengthD = new Array();
 for(var i = 0; i < hwMany; i ++){
  if(i == 0) {
   genrandSub();
   subdivisionN[i] = fractionN;
   lengthD[i] = fractionD;
  }
  else {
   var index = 0;
   rand = genrandSub();
   if(findConvergence (fractionN, fractionD,subdivisionN[i-1], lengthD[i-1]) != true){
    var state = false;
    while(state == false){
     rand = genrandSub();
     state = findConvergence (fractionN, fractionD,subdivisionN[i-1], lengthD[i-1]);
     index += 1;
     if(index == 6){
      state = true;
     }
    }
    if(index == 6){
     genPattern(hwMany);"here is the problem"
    }
    else{
     subdivisionN[i] = fractionN;
     lengthD[i] = fractionD; 
    }
   }
   else{
    subdivisionN[i] = fractionN;
    lengthD[i] = fractionD;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

So I realized that in this function, the way I coded it, can be called recursively even before the end of the "for loop". so I've changed to this:

```js
function genPattern (hwMany) {
 var subdivisionN = new Array();
 var lengthD = new Array();
 for(var i = 0; i < hwMany; i ++){
  if(i == 0) {
   genrandSub();
   subdivisionN[i] = fractionN;
   lengthD[i] = fractionD;
  }
  else {
   var index = 0;
   genrandSub();
   if(findConvergence (fractionN, fractionD,subdivisionN[i-1], lengthD[i-1]) != true){
    var state = false;
    while(state == false){
     genrandSub();
     state = findConvergence (fractionN, fractionD,subdivisionN[i-1], lengthD[i-1]);
     index += 1;
     if(index == 100){
      post("MANY");
      post();
      break;
     }
    }
    subdivisionN[i] = fractionN;
    lengthD[i] = fractionD; 
   }
   else{
    subdivisionN[i] = fractionN;
    lengthD[i] = fractionD;
   }
  }
 }
 if(index == 100){
  genPattern(hwMany);"now is in the rigth place"
 }
}
```

Now I can understand that the previous code was wrong, but I cannot understand Why I could run the code anyway! Somebody could comment please?